# Using awk conditional statement with shell module on the tabular data is not working as expected in Ansible

Tags: awk, ansible

I have a requirement as mentioned below.
I have to access the last column from the table, shown below, of data (obtained from the remote node), using an Ansible playbook.

```
PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path   
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State 
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active 
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked 
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked 
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive 
PL-4  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active 
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked 
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive 

This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

I have to use the content of the last column in a conditional statement to draw some conclusions based on it.

For example, the paths which are specified in the last but one column, corrsponding to the blade ID mentioned in column 1

1. are in working condition if the value/content in the last (i.e.,Path state) column is either Active or Blocked
2. are in non-working condition if the value/content in the last (i.e.,Path state) column is Inactive

I have tried a playbook like this.

```
---
# The objective of this playbook is to use this command "sudo dsc-show-sctp-assoc"
# and check the status of Check the status of SCTP Associations.
- name: Playbook for Checking the status of SCTP Associations
  hosts: all  
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Getting SCTP Association status details and saving them to a text file
    shell: dsc-show-sctp-assoc | tee sctp.txt  # "dsc-show-sctp-assoc" is used to get the tabular data from the remote node

  - name: IDNETIYING THE PASS AND FAIL CASES
    shell: cat sctp.txt | awk -F "|" {if ($NF=="Inactive") print $0, " ", '===>', "FAIL"; else print $0, " ", "====>","PASS";}'
  register: pass_fail_cases

  - name: PRINTING THE PASS AND FAIL CASES
    debug: 
      msg: "{{pass_fail_cases.stdout_lines }}"
...
```

The expected output is shown below

```
PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path 
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State 
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     |*10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive ===> "FAIL"
PL-3  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive ===> "FAIL"
      
This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

whereas I am getting the below output

```
PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path 
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State 
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     |*10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive ===> "PASS"
PL-3  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive ===> "PASS"
      
This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

I guess that the conditional statement (if condition) of AWK command is not working as expected and hence everything is resulted as "PASS".

I tried it multiple ways. But none of them gave me the expected output.

Can someone please help to let me know where I am going wrong?

***PS: I tried using AWK command here. Please suggest me the other approcahes that I can follow to get the expected output, if any***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
!NF{ print; found="" }
(/^(PROGRESS|[[:space:]]+|Blade|Id|-{6}\+)|^This table was generated:/ && !found){
  if(/^-{6}\+/){ found=1 }
  print
  next
}
found{
  print $0, "===>", ($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"":"\"PASS\"")
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to use it as a one-liner to use it in ansible playbook try following one-liner then:

`awk '!NF{print;found=""} (/^(PROGRESS|[[:space:]]+|Blade|Id|-{6}\+)|^This table was generated:/ && !found){if(/^-{6}\+/){found=1};print;next} found{print $0, "===>", ($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"":"\"PASS\"")}' Input_file`

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF{ print; found="" }         ##If NF is NULL then print that line and Nullify found here.
(/^(PROGRESS|[[:space:]]+|Blade|Id|-{6}\+)|^This table was generated:/ && !found){  ##Checking conditions if line starts from PROGRESS OR spaces OR Blade OR Id OR 6 dashes then do following.
  if(/^-{6}\+/){ found=1 }  ##Checking if line starts from 6 dashes then set found to 1.
  print                        ##Printing line here.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found{                         ##Checking condition if found is NOT NULL.
  print $0, "===>", ($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"":"\"PASS\"") ##Then printing current line followed by either Fail or Pass based on last field as per OP request.
}
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It is working if the spaces before and after "colon" (:)  "\"FAIL\"" : "\"PASS\"" are  removed. 

Otherwise, it is giving syntax error.

Comment: @ashokswarna, Your welcome. Thanks for letting know the fix. Request you if you could also make an edit where you did the fix that part to my answer that can be helpful to future users. Make an edit and I will approve it then, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @ashokswarna I see you made an edit titled `removed the spaces **before and after "colon" (:) "\"FAIL\"" : "\"PASS\""** to avoid syntax error.` that does exactly that. Spaces around the `:` aren't a problem though so whatever problem you were having that was producing a syntax error, it wasn't spaces around the `:` that was causing it.

Comment: I see in your question you were calling awk with a mixture of single and double quotes interwoven throughout: `cat sctp.txt | awk -F "|" {if ($NF=="Inactive") print $0, " ", '===>', "FAIL"; else print $0, " ", "====>","PASS";}'`. That's not how to call awk, though, so if you tried to adapt Ravinder's answer to look like that, that would cause breakage.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk -F '|' '!NF {main=0} !main; /^-{3}/ {main=1; next} main {print $0, "===>", ($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"" : "\"PASS\"")}' sctp.txt

PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"
PL-4  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"

This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

Or to make it readable:

```bash
awk -F '|' '
!NF {main=0}
!main
/^-{3}/ {main=1; next}
main {
   print $0, "===>", ($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"" : "\"PASS\"")
}' sctp.txt
```

This solutions uses a flag called `main` to indicate when your main body of report starts. Initially `main` is zero, when we encounter `-----` line then we set `main=1`. Last block adds `PASS` or `FAIL` when `main==1` depending on value of `$NF`.

Comment: In this case, a condition equivalent to if-else-end is implemented. If I have to implement a condition equivalent to if- elseif -else -end, How can I do that ??

Comment: You can do something like this: `($NF ~ /Inactive/ ? "\"FAIL\"" : ($NF ~ /Unknown/ ? "\"REJECTED\"" : "\"PASS\""))`

Comment: In case if It is required to delete an entire column [let us say "Paths (* - current data transfer path)"] from the output (with no modification in the input), what could be the better way to do it ?

Comment: That will be very different from the problem asked here. I suggest you post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { map["Active"]=map["Blocked"]="PASS"; map["Inactive"]="FAIL" }
    { print $0 ($NF in map ? " ===> \"" map[$NF] "\"" : "") }
' sctp.txt
PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"
PL-4  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"

This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

By the way, in your code you have:

```
shell: cat sctp.txt | awk -F "|" {if ($NF=="Inactive") print $0, " ", '===>', "FAIL"; else print $0, " ", "====>","PASS";}'
```

idk why you're swapping back and forth between singe and double quotes like that but - don't. A valid syntax for what that line is trying to do would be:

```
shell: cat sctp.txt | awk -F "|" '{if ($NF=="Inactive") print $0, " ", "===>", "FAIL"; else print $0, " ", "====>","PASS";}'
```

which could be improved to (but still won't work, I'm just showing valid syntax, not correcting semantics):

```
shell: awk -F '|' '{print $0, " ", "===>", ($NF=="Inactive" ? "FAIL" : "PASS")}' sctp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g}awk '!/[|+]/ || _+__*(_ -= /^[+-]+$/) || sub("$",  " ===> \"" substr(\
         "PASSFAIL", 5^(!_<NF), 4*!+_) "\"")' FS='[|] Inactive[ \t]*$'     \_=1 


######### # or preferably, not hard-coding in the "1" :

mawk 'BEGIN { FS = "[|][ \t]+Inactive[ \t]*$" 
               _+=_+=_=__ ^=  _<_
      } !/[|+]/ || __ + (__ -= /^[+-]+$/)*-!_ || sub("$",\ 
       " ===> \"" substr("PASSFAIL", (--_+--_)^(_==NF), _^=_)'
```

=

```
PROGRESS: Starting connection towards ss7caf stack...
          Please wait, the output can take up to several minutes

Blade | EP | AS  | Paths (* - current data       | Path   
Id    | Id | Id  | transfer path)                | State 
------+----+-----+-------------------------------+---------
PL-3  |  1 | 1-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.161 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.116.178.162 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.161 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.116.178.162 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"
PL-4  |  1 | 4-1 | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.130 | Active  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.0 - 10.250.161.138 | Blocked  ===> "PASS"
      |    |     | 10.201.176.2 - 10.250.161.130 | Inactive  ===> "FAIL"

This table was generated: 2022-03-08 11:11:38 AEDT
```

Comment: Can you please add the Explanation  to help me understand ?

Comment: @ashokswarna :  split it by components of the logical ORs `| |` : first part is no `|` or `+`, meaning header and footer stuff, including empty lines, second part is to track location of `——+——+———...`  so know when to begin appending `PASS / FAIL` - those with `Inactive` would have `NF==2` because `FS` was defined that way, `5^true` is same as `substr( …., 5, 4)` , `5^false` is anything to `0th power`, so that's just `substr(…,1, 4)` - that's why it would append the correct status from one single lookup string.